# Python xml parse Attribute Error ''set' object has no attribute 'items'''

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse [this](https://hwe.niwa.co.nz/search/summary/Startdate/01-01-2000/Enddate/01-06-2020/Regions/all/Hazards/all/Impacts/all/Keywords/none/numberOfEvents/20/page/1/xml) xml using python `xml.etree`. I am getting an error 'set' object has no attribute 'items'. The following is what I tried.

```
import requests
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://hwe.niwa.co.nz/search/summary/Startdate/01-01-2000/Enddate/01-06-2020/Regions/all/Hazards/all/Impacts/all/Keywords/none/numberOfEvents/20/page/1/xml'
r = requests.get(url)
xmlstr = r.text
print(xmlstr)
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)

ns = {'http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist'}
results = root.findall("events", ns)

for i in results:
    sDate = i.find('StartDate', ns)
    abstract = i.find('Abstract', ns)
    ......
```

Comment: You should add the part of the code that causes the error.

Comment: @Jack Fleeting: I have put the code that generates the error in my question.

Comment: No, it's not there. Let's try this - what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting : I want to extract the details into a Pandas dataframe such as start date, abstract, location...I have edited the question.